# Use ng-click function in swipe - ionic v1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, swipe

I've got slide page on ionic v1 and it uses prev and next button. Like this:

```
<button id="" class="button button-slide prev no-animation" ng-click="prev()" ng-show="activeIndex > 0" >
BACK
</button>
```

It works good. But I need same result on swipe. It is not triggered because it is click function.

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: see [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-swipe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has built-in support for swipe left and right. The docs are located here with examples:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngSwipeLeft
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngSwipeRight

Answer (score 0):

here you go bud! there is a built in angular directive for this
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngSwipeLeft